# Detect if Router supports Multicast

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sockets, udp, multicast

Is there a way to programmatically detect if a router supports multicast? Either in plain `C` (BSD sockets) or preferably in some higher level fashion on OSX (`Objective-C`/`Cocoa`).

Update: I'm assuming here, that we have only one process running to determine the multicast support (so approaches suggesting multiple clients on separate machines are not relevant here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen on 224.0.0.1 for 125s for an IGMP query but this wont detect static multicast routing.

The only sure method is to have a transport to another host on a different LAN segment and test a join & send.  Still then dependent upon sparse or dense mode routing its not an immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

The best way: you have to have atleast 2 nodes on the both sides of a Multicast ROUTER.
For example:

PC1 (Sender)---->>-- Router ---->>-----PC2 (Receiver)

At sender side (PC1) use vlc to send multicast packets to some multicast IP say 235.1.1.1
Now at receiver side (PC2) you can use [mcfirst utility](http://www.venaas.no/multicast/ssmping/) . With proper combination of option you can know if PC2 can receive multicast packets.

Above works for both IPv4 and IPv6.